# Python subprocess to communicate with non GUI

Tags: python, subprocess

I am trying to communicate with a non-GUI software through python. Basically, after starting the process I need to wait for a response and type certain commands in the terminal. However the following code is not working as subprocess.Popen terminates the process.

```py
process = subprocess.Popen(f"Multiwfn_noGUI 178_aromat.fchk", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
output, _ = process.communicate()
if "based on wavefunction" in str(output):
    string_val = "y"
    input_bytes = string_val.encode('utf-8')
    process.stdin.write(input_bytes)
    process.stdin.flush()
    output, _ = process.communicate()

    if "300 Other functions (Part 3)" in output:
        string_val = "25"
        input_bytes = string_val.encode('utf-8')
        process.stdin.write(input_bytes)
        process.stdin.flush()
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "homa_calc.py", line 285, in <module>
    process.stdin.write(input_bytes)
ValueError: write to closed file
```

Comment: `process.communicate()` does not return until the process has completed.  Why don't you just read from `process.stdout`?

Comment: Is this a unix like system (not Windows)? Then `pexpect` may be a good option.